# Scrapy CrawlSpider: Getting data before extracting link

Tags: scrapy

In CrawlSpider, how can I scrape the marked field "4 days ago" in the image before extracting each link?
The below-mentioned CrawlSpider is working fine. But in 'parse_item' I want to add a new field named 'Add posted' where I want to get the field marked on the image.

[image]

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class PropertySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'property'
    
    allowed_domains = ['www.openrent.co.uk']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.openrent.co.uk/properties-to-rent/london?term=London&skip='+ str(x) for x in range(0, 5, 20)
        ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@id='property-data']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'Title': response.xpath("//h1[@class='property-title']/text()").get(),
            'Price': response.xpath("//h3[@class='perMonthPrice price-title']/text()").get(),
            'Links': response.url,
            'Add posted': ?
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `Rule` object of the scrapy crawl spider, the extracted link's text is saved in a meta field of the request named `link_text`. You can obtain this value in the `parse_item` method and extract the time information using regex. You can read more about it from the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules). See below example.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import re

class PropertySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'property'
    
    allowed_domains = ['www.openrent.co.uk']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.openrent.co.uk/properties-to-rent/london?term=London&skip='+ str(x) for x in range(0, 5, 20)
        ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@id='property-data']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        link_text = response.request.meta.get("link_text")
        m = re.search(r"(Last Updated.*ago)", link_text)
        if m:
            posted = m.group(1).replace("\xa0", " ")
        
        yield {
            'Title': response.xpath("//h1[@class='property-title']/text()").get(),
            'Price': response.xpath("//h3[@class='perMonthPrice price-title']/text()").get(),
            'Links': response.url,
            "Add posted": posted
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To show in a loop, you can use the following xpath to receive that data point:

```py
x = response.xpath('//div[@class="timeStamp"]')
for i in x:
    yield {'result': i.xpath("./i/following-sibling::text()").get().strip() }
```