# Grab the link text from the rule in Scrapy link extractor

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have such a set of rules for extracting links:

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('collections',), deny='products')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='products'), callback='parse_item')
    )
```

is it possible to somehow capture the text of the "collections" link (**(response.css('a[href*="collections"]::text').get())**) and pass this text to parse_item (for example, to a variable)

Comment: What do you mean by text of the "collections" link? This all sounds like you want to use cb_kwargs with your Request, but tbh I'm not sure if I understand your question

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356847/scrapy-crawlspider-getting-data-before-extracting-link/71364616#71364616)